# Test redirection functionality in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

#### Scenario :

I have following test case in which I want to test scenario as, if user found with usertype **superadmin** then redirect user to **/home** route and if user not found redirect him to **/superadmin/setup** route. Tried multiple approch but can't figure out. How can pass this test?

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

#### Test Case :

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class SuperAdminRegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testRegistrationForm()
    {
        factory(User::class)->create(['usertype' => 'superadmin']);
        $user = User::getUserFromUsertype('superadmin');
        //If valid user is found with usertype 'superadmin' then
            // $this->get('/home');
            // $this->assertStatus(200);
        //Else user not found with given usertype then
           // $this->get('/superadmin/setup');
           // $this->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->assertRedirectedTo($uri, $with = []);
```

maybe try something like that

This PHPUnit method will assert whether you have been redirected to the $uri you provide within the arguments.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/testing

you can read more about this in the official laravel documentation for testing

Comment: While your code might technically answer the question you might want to include some explanation as to why it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, **do not use if else statements in your test methods**. Since you want to test all the possible cases, but if else statements selects only one case.

From experience, I recommend you use two test methods as follows:

```
public function testSuperAdminCanViewRegistrationForm()
{
    factory(User::class)->create(['usertype' => 'superadmin']);
    $user = User::getUserFromUsertype('superadmin');

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $response = $this->get('/home');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}

public function testNonSuperAdminCanViewRegistrationForm()
{
    factory(User::class)->create(['usertype' => 'non_superadmin']);
    $user = User::getUserFromUsertype('non_superadmin');

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $response = $this->get('/home');
    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertRedirect('/superadmin/setup');
}
```

**NB: I worked in Laravel ^6.0**

Answer (score 0):

Create a 2nd user that is not of type superadmin. Make sure they get redirected to /superadmin/setup.